# Exoplayer 2.9.4 SmoothStreaming

Tags: android, streaming, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

I'm using explayer 2.9.4, and I have no idea how to create smooth-streaming with Exoplayer. I'm searching over internet with days but nothing found.
My code is this, but this is for normal streaming I need with DASH

```
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
    Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(videoURL);
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory( Util.getUserAgent(this, "My Streamer"));
    mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory) .createMediaSource(videoURI);
```

and is working tried some code from stackoverflow like this:

```
     DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory( Util.getUserAgent(this, "FTV Stream Albania"));
        dashMediaSource = new DashMediaSource(videoURI, dataSourceFactory, new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory), null, null);
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
```

but I get error :

> ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
>
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT
>   G@��B�%���������...@2:79 in java.io.InputStreamReader@c587547) 
>           at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:105)
>           at........

Documentation is very poor. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sulution was I added two files from [ExoPlayer Github Soruce codes](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer):

**DownloadTracker.java** and **DemoDownloadService.java** and then from PlayerActivity.java just got codes I need, now it works great.

Comment: can you please explore in detail what are the changes done..? i also have the same issue..!

Comment: could you please share a snippet from the PlayerActivity.java that you took? I'm having the same issue but not able to get a workaround it.

Comment: Please explain a bit more, about this solution... i'm facing same issue.

Answer (score -1):

**For DASH steaming with ExoPlayerV2.9.4:**

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, getPackageName())); //1. Create the data source object
MediaSource dashMediaSource = new DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .createMediaSource(mUri); //2. Create mediaSource object of DASH media type 

TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory =
                    new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(); //3. Create AdaptiveTrackSelection factory object 
TrackSelector trackSelector =
                    new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory); //4. Create DefaultTrackSelector object
exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector); //5. Create exoPlayer object
exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource); //6. prepare the creates exoPlayer object with mediaSource (dash mediaSource in your case)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm getting this error: ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error. com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ������ ftypisom������...@1:923 in java.io.InputStreamReader@e2892e)  I'm using ExoPlayerV2.9.4

Comment: @Arjun, Actually, the "������ ftypisom�������" corresponds to the first bytes of an h.264 encoded ISO Media container (e.g. MP4, 3GPP, or MOV). Here, ExoPlayer is trying to play an ISO Media (a binary file) as a dash XML manifest. 
Seems like you are hitting an invalid token in the XML stream. Probably your DASH manifest is malformed.